# ground filter blur transition issue

Tags: css, filter, transition, backdrop

Pressing the button blurs the background, but while transitioning, the edges of the div do not transition well. This problem exists in all browsers except firefox how can i fix it?

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
            
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {              
    div.classList.toggle('blur');           
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2763927/pexels-photo-2763927.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1')no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

div {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    transition: 1s ease;    
}

.blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    transition: 1s ease;        
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="cube"></div>    
<button>BLUR BUTTON</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the image fills `<body>`, but the `.blur` is in the `<div>`, which is only 900x900 pixels.

Quick fix:

Change: `var div = document.querySelector('div');`

to: `var div = document.body;`

Or: move the `background: url(..); background-size: ..` to the `div` and take it from there.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var div = document.body;
            
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {              
    div.classList.toggle('blur');           
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2763927/pexels-photo-2763927.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1')no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

div {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    transition: 1s ease;    
}

.blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    transition: 1s ease;        
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="cube"></div>    
<button>BLUR BUTTON</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this didn't solve the problem my friend. the borders of the blurred part are broken while switching again